# Does the ARN of an AWS Managed Certificate change when it is renewed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

I have a simple question, but I'm having trouble finding an answer.

When using AWS Certificate Manager, does the certificate ARN change when the certificate is renewed?

Some context:

I have a Cloudformation template that creates an autoscaling group + ELB.  I use IAM certificates for HTTPS.  This is a pain, because when the certificate expires, the ARN in the template needs to be changed to point to the new certificate.

My understanding is, if I switch to AWS Certificate Manager, I can use the ACM certificate ARN in my template, and the certificate can then be replaced/renewed behind the scenes, without me having to change the ARN in my template.  I'm essentially abstracted from the underlying changes.

Is that a correct assumption?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a *managed* certificate, then yes - the ARN stays that same for ACM certificates. However, if you imported your own certificate in to ACM, automatic renewals will not occur, and uploading a new one will result in a new ARN.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html):

> When ACM renews a certificate, the certificate's Amazon Resource Name (ARN) remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Those who looking for answers for imported certificates, I want to point that renewal of imported certificate by reimporting will not change its ARN. I found this from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html).

> To renew an imported certificate, you can obtain a new certificate from your certificate issuer and then manually reimport it into ACM. **This action preserves the certificate's association and its Amazon Resource name (ARN).**

So renewal of imported certificate by reimporting will not change ARN of certificate.

I tested it with dummy certificate I created with easyrsa.
Created a certificate with 10 days life(?) to expiration date and imported it to ACM. Then recreated same certificate with 30 days life(?) to expiration date.
Then I renewed existing 10 days left certificate by reimporting with 30 days left certificate using `aws acm import-certificate` command with `--certificate-arn` option. **After reimporting(renewal), certificate ARN didn't change.**